# Overflow hidden bug: Mobile browser

Tags: html, safari, overflow

The HTML renders well in desktop but in mobile browser (iOS, Blackberry), there's no scroller for #child.

Is there any workaround for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/t9y99/

```
<div id='parent' style='width:300px; height:200px; overflow:hidden;'>
   <div id='child' style='width:300px; height:200px; overflow:auto;'>
    <h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1><h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scrolls just fine in iOS Safari?

Comment: For low model iPhone (3GS) & Blackberry, there's no scroll bar in child.

Comment: Okay, lower model iPhone or earlier iOS, have you tested that?